# Enable chrome.contextMenus in normal and incognito at the same time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to show contextMenu for my extension to show in both normal and incognito if both window are open?

I've tried the code below but it appears only in incognito window. If I want to show it in normal window, I need to close the incognito window.

```
let changeLogId = (chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext ? 'changelogIncognito' : 'changelog');
chrome.contextMenus.remove(changeLogId);
chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: changeLogId,
      title: "View Change Log",
      contexts: ["browser_action"]
});
```

P.S. I put this code in my manifest's background script

```
"background" : {
    "scripts" : ["dashboard.js"],
    "persistent" : false
  }
```

Comment: @wOxxOm no, that's not the case. The scenario is, the chrome extension icon appears in both normal window and incognito window. However, if both window are open at the same time, only the [contextMenu](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus) in incognito window is working.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome.